# c# json pull request

Tags: c#, json

My JSON is the below:

[image: json image]

```
 string url = "https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?languages=tr&query=Necati+Şaşmaz&limit=1&key=AIzaSyB_w5S8Bv3P4zn7pqu6if49_4bHx9YMmSY";
 HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
 string jsonVerisi = "";
 using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
 {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
      //jsonVerisi adlı değişkene elde ettiği veriyi atıyoruz.
      jsonVerisi = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

How do I get the images selected location with json?

Comment: Have you looked at newtonsoft.json? Its a json parser and you can use a dynamic object to prevent creating the c# objects in your code if you just want that one value.

Comment: Include your image as text/code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. If the returned JSON content schema (structure) is always same then try creating a class as below

*Note: These classes are generated using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)*

```
    public class Context {
    [JsonProperty("@vocab")] //This is to map the property name with @symbol in JSON content to this class property
     public string vocab { get; set; }
     public string goog { get; set; }
     public string EntitySearchResult { get; set; }
     public string detailedDescription { get; set; }
     public string resultScore { get; set; }
     public string kg { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailedDescription {
     public string articleBody { get; set; }
     public string url { get; set; }
     public string license { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result {
     [JsonProperty("@id")]
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("@type")]
     public List<string> type { get; set; }
     public string description { get; set; }
     public DetailedDescription detailedDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemListElement {
     [JsonProperty("@type")]
     public string type { get; set; }
     public Result result { get; set; }
     public double resultScore { get; set; }
    }

    public class SearchResult {
     [JsonProperty("@context")]
     public Context context { get; set; }
     [JsonProperty("@type")]
     public string type { get; set; }
     public List<ItemListElement> itemListElement { get; set; }
    }
```

and then try deserialize the `jsonVerisi` value using [JsonConvert from Newtonsoft Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) as below

```
    using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse) {
            using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                //jsonVerisi adlı değişkene elde ettiği veriyi atıyoruz.
                jsonVerisi = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //Deserialize
                var searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResult>(jsonVerisi);
                //Now you could get the needed value as below
                if(searchResult != null) {
                    foreach(var item in searchResult.itemListElement) {
                        var resultTypes = item.result != null ? item.result.type : null;

                        //Iterate through resultTypes to get the list of values
                        //e.g. for person
                        //var personType = resultTypes[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

2. Instead of creating a new class, use the type [Newtonsoft Json.NET JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) (which provides the element access similar to `Dictionary<string, object>` with `JSON key or property name`) and deserialize the JSON content as below.

   ```
   using(HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)     {
           using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
               //jsonVerisi adlı değişkene elde ettiği veriyi atıyoruz.
               jsonVerisi = reader.ReadToEnd();

               var searchResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonVerisi);
               if(searchResult != null) {
                   var itemListElement = searchResult["itemListElement"];
                   if(itemListElement != null) {
                       foreach(var item in itemListElement.ToList()) {
                           var result = item["result"];
                           var resultTypes = result != null && result["@type"].HasValues ? result["@type"].Values<string>().ToList() : null;

                           //Iterate through resultTypes to get the list of values
                           //e.g. for person
                           //var personType = resultTypes[1];
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```

I hope this would help in your case!

*Tip: It's better to use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) type which has many useful methods to perform HTTP request.*

Comment: Good to hear that!